# Is it possible to use repeated measures ANOVA/ANCOVA with three change scores when one of which is an aggregate of the other two?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, pre-post-comparison

I have one independent variable and a dependent variable measured at three time points in a longitudinal cohort study, and plan to analyse them with a mixed between-within ANOVA. I have considered examining change scores, rather than the raw scores.

Thus, with the change scores I'd have three dependent (within-subjects) variables as follows:

1. the difference between time 1 and time 2
2. the difference between time 2 and time 3
3. the **difference between time 1 and time 3**

Is it possible or even plausible to use that third DV in a repeated measures procedure (I've been advised in loose terms to do so)? I'm doubtful, because it seems to me not to be another repeat measure, but rather an aggregate of the other two.

It's a bit of a head-melter for me. I feel I'd be better off just examining the raw scores. The reason I moved away from raw scores: skewed data with outliers that couldn't be reliably transformed. I have however since discovered bootstrapping - perhaps I should do this instead...?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: I'd like to stick with ANOVA as the analytic method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your intuition is correct that there is something off about the change scores. Those 3 scores will be linearly dependent and your ANOVA will not work. In other words, there are 2 degrees of freedom for the time effect, which you can convert to any two contrasts that make sense, but not three. So I would not do that.

There is nothing wrong with the repeated measures analysis you were planning on doing. If you are worried about the outliers, you can try analysing the data both with and without them and see if your conclusions change drastically. If they don't, then you're probably fine. Note that removal of outliers means that your design will no longer be balanced, but you can use a mixed effects model instead.

The F statistics for the ANOVA rely on the group totals being normally distributed, so you can get away with some departures from normality in the raw data and rely on the Central Limit Theorem. The skewedness may not be as big a problem as you fear.